# Apply tag for each line in xlst?

Tags: xslt

How to apply tag for every line

### Input:

<preformat>
GRANT JOHN READ
EMP.SALARY
GRANT JOHN READ
EMP.NAME
</preformat>

### Output:

<pre>
<code>GRANT JOHN READ</code>
<code>EMP.SALARY</code>
<code>GRANT JOHN READ</code>
<code>EMP.NAME</code>
</pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **XSLT 2.0**

you can use

```
<xsl:template match="preformat">
    <pre>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '&#xa;')">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) ne ''">
             <code>
                 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
             </code>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </pre>
</xsl:template>
```

You can see this transformation at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/eiQZDbh

also for **XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="preformat">
    <pre>
    <xsl:call-template name="code">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </pre>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="code">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($data, '&#xa;')">
               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="normalize-space(substring-before($data, '&#xa;')) = ''">
                       <xsl:if test="substring-after($data, '&#xa;')">
                           <xsl:call-template name="code">
                               <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring-after($data, '&#xa;')"/>
                           </xsl:call-template>
                       </xsl:if>
                   </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:otherwise>
                       <code>
                           <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($data, '&#xa;'))"/>
                       </code>
                       <xsl:if test="substring-after($data, '&#xa;')">
                           <xsl:call-template name="code">
                               <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring-after($data, '&#xa;')"/>
                           </xsl:call-template>
                       </xsl:if>
                   </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <code>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($data)"/>
            </code>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

you can see transformation at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWcDMej

Comment: Thanks its works well, but we need formatting tags like (<b> and <i>). How we will process

Comment: Thanks its works well, but we need formatting tags like (<b> and <i>). How we will process <preformat>
GRANT <b>JOHN</b> READ
EMP.SALARY
<i>GRANT</i> JOHN READ
EMP.NAME
</preformat>

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the preformat tag will be a single text block. Pass  to a template, substring-before ($text, '
') will give you the first line and then call the same function with substring-after until it's empty.